# Python tree datatype add child operation results in recursive children

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have a tree generated at python and I just simply want to append a new child to a parent however, Although the children of the child no is empty, it seems to happend that child node becomes child of both parent and itself.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.child_nodes = []
    self.data = None
    ...
    self.parent = None

def init_tree(self, data, child_nodes=[], ...):
    self.child_nodes = child_nodes
    self.data = data
    ...

def add_child_node(self, node):
    ancestors = self.get_ancestors()
    if node is not self and node not in ancestors:
        self.child_nodes.append(node)
        node.parent = self

def get_ancestors(self):
    ancestor = self.parent
    ancestors = [ancestor]
    try:
        while ancestor.parent != None:
            ancestors.append(ancestor)
            parent = self.parent
            ancestor = parent.get_parent()
        return ancestors
    # Node is root. Root's parent is None
    except AttributeError:
        return []


def my_funct(self):
    ...
    child_node = RandomWalkTree()       
    child_node.init_tree(data=data)
    self.add_child_node(child_node)
```

my_funct results in a childnode with a child_nodes containing itself recursively. Which points am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and share for the ones that has a similar one. The line in init function

```
self.child_nodes = child_nodes
```

results in the situation I have changed it to

```
self.child_nodes = []
```

and removed the parameter. Problem solved.